# Spring Webflux - Proper way to throw checked custom exception (not RuntimeException)

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, spring-webflux

May I ask what is the proper way to throw checked custom exception in Spring webflux please?
I would like to insist, it is about **checked custom exception**, like MyException.java, not something like RuntimeException, and it is about **throwing** exception, not handling exception.

I tried the following :

```
@Controller
@SpringBootApplication
public class QuestionHowToThrowException {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(QuestionHowToThrowException.class);
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/question", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Mono<ResponseEntity<QuestionResponse>> question(@RequestBody QuestionRequest questionRequest) {
        Mono<FirstStep> firstStepMono = WebClient.create().post().uri("http://firstWebService:8111/getFirstStep")
                .body(questionRequest.getThing(), String.class).retrieve().bodyToMono(FirstStep.class);
        Mono<SecondStep> secondStepMono = firstStepMono.map(oneFirstStep -> getSecondStepFromFirstStepAfterCheck(oneFirstStep));
        return secondStepMono.map(oneSecondStep -> ResponseEntity.ok(new QuestionResponse(oneSecondStep.getSecondThing())));
    }

    private SecondStep getSecondStepFromFirstStepAfterCheck(FirstStep firstStep) throws MyException {
        if (firstStep.getThingNeedsToCheckCanThrowException().equals("exception")) {
            throw new MyException("exception");
        } else {
            return new SecondStep(firstStep.getThingNeedsToCheckCanThrowException() + "good");
        }
    }

    public class QuestionRequest {
        private String thing;
        public String getThing() {
            return thing;
        }
    }

    public class QuestionResponse {
        private String response;
        public QuestionResponse(String response) {
            this.response = response;
        }
    }

    public class FirstStep {
        private String thingNeedsToCheckCanThrowException;
        public String getThingNeedsToCheckCanThrowException() {
            return thingNeedsToCheckCanThrowException;
        }
    }

    public class SecondStep {
        private String secondThing;
        public SecondStep(String secondThing) {
            this.secondThing = secondThing;
        }
        public String getSecondThing() {
            return secondThing;
        }
    }

}
```

This is not possible, since there in an unhandled exception in getSecondStepFromFirstStepAfterCheck method.

If I throw and propagate, private SecondStep getSecondStepFromFirstStepAfterCheck(FirstStep firstStep) throws MyException the lambda caller method is not happy.

What is the cleanest and proper way to throw custom exception in webflux please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading through your sample code, it looks like you are trying to introduce some error handling with on your `Mono`.

You can create an unchecked exception by extending the `RuntimeException` class. If you want a checked exception that enforces handling, you can simply extend `Exception`.

```
public class MyException extends RuntimeException {
    public MyException(String msg) {
       super(s);
    }
}
```

The cleanest way to throw an exception with the Reactor project is really just to throw it. There are error handling functions that allow you to provide different flows to certain error cases.

The good news is you have several options that provides some flow control for error handling.

Project Reactor provides several of these methods on the [`Mono`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html) object.

`doOnError()`,`onErrorContinue()`,`onErrorReturn()`,`onErrorStop()`,`onErrorMap()`

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve with the following sample code.

```
 return Mono.error(new MyException("exception"));
        } else {
 return Mono.just(new SecondStep(firstStep.getThingNeedsToCheckCanThrowException() + "good"));
```

But this looks like a good case for a `onErrorMap()` since it looks like you are trying to translate some exception here

```
return Mono.just(new SecondStep(firstStep.getThingNeedsToCheckCanThrowException() + "good")
   .onErrorMap(e -> "translated result");
```

Comment: Hello @shinjw, Thank you for your advice.

I followed your idea, but I am still blocked.
I now do "The cleanest way to throw an exception with the Reactor project is really just to throw it"

Please see the updated signature     private SecondStep getSecondStepFromFirstStepAfterCheck(FirstStep firstStep) throws MyException {

However, this is not compiling, since the caller now has an unhandled exception.
Could you please provide a snippet?

Comment: Is MyException an Exception or a RuntimeException? If it is a checked `Exception` then you will have to rethrow your exception as a RuntimeException to bubble it up into your Mono flow.

Comment: `catch(Exception e) { throw new RuntimeException(e) }`

Comment: You are correct, it is an Exception.
public class MyException extends Exception {

I do not want to start another topic here of checked versus unchecked exception, but I would like to avoid throwing Runtime Exception. Would it be possible to achieve the same without going through this "re-throw" please?

Answer (score 1):

For our applications, we have our custom base exception extend from RuntimeException. We then have standard exception handling that looks for our custom exception for special handling before returning results back to the end user. This allows us to use normal throws mechanics since we want all exceptions thrown to ripple up the top level of the call.

For performance concerns webflux and reactive are slightly lower performance on a per call basis especially for calls that don't need to do any parallelization. However once load is put onto the system it tends to become more performant primarily related to garbage collection. Overhead from the difference between map and flatMap should be negligible at best.